# Why am I able to use Application as default bindings in ViewModelComponent with Hilt?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

From the [article](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#component-default), I know each Hilt component comes with a set of default bindings that Hilt can inject as dependencies. you can see the Image A.

And the `ViewModelComponent` has only one default bindings `SavedStateHandle` based the article above.

Why am I able to use `Application` as default bindings in `ViewModelComponent` with Hilt in Code A?

```
@HiltViewModel
class PlaySoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
   private val appContext: Application,         // It's Ok, I have tested.
   private val playSound: IPlaySound,
   private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
): ViewModel(){
   ...
}
```

**Image A**

[image]

Comment: A component can use dependencies from other components . its same as when u inject a Singleton repository in a `ViewModel`.  `@ApplicationContext` in turns comes from `SingletonComponent` .. See the code examples in the link u attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this graph (https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#component-hierarchy) , We can access bindings of parent components and as you have mentioned that `SingletonComponent` have `Application` as default binding , `ViewModel` is able to access `Application`