# Why can I reference Application in ViewModel when I use Hilt in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I use Hilt as DI in Android Studio project. I know *"A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context."*

So you can find that there is a warning information in Image A for Code A.

But the `ViewModelComponent` of Hilt has bound `Application`, you can see the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76152338/why-am-i-able-to-use-application-as-default-bindings-in-viewmodelcomponent-with).

**1:**  I don't know why  `private val appContext: Application` in ViewModel doesn't display  warning information, does it mean I can use `Application` in `ViewModel` when I use Hilt?   could you tell me?

**2:** BTW, `private val appContext: Application` displays the information below, why?

*Constructor parameter is never used as a property*

**Code A**

```
@HiltViewModel
class RecordSoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val myContext: Context,    //Android Studio displays warning information
    private val appContext: Application,                   // Why doesn't it dsiplay warning information
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
): ViewModel()
{
     ...
}
```

**Image A**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might just be the lint seeing Context inside a ViewModel() and complaining about it. Because you might be giving a Context that lives shorter than the ViewModel.

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    //will complain about leaking context
    val ctx: Context = Context()
}
```

Injecting something that uses ApplicationContext into a ViewModel is a valid use case.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object WorkManagerModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideWorkManager(@ApplicationContext context: Context): WorkManager {
        return WorkManager.getInstance(context)
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val workManager: WorkManager
)
```

For 2: Lint is telling you to remove private val. Since you are not using it as a property, val/var is not needed.

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) {
    //not complaints about property
    val myId = savedStateHandle.get<String>("MyId")
}
```

If you want to use it as a property you must add val/var.

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) {
    fun getMyIdFromSaveState(): String? {
        //will complain that it does not know savedStateHandle, you must add val or var.
        return savedStateHandle.get<String>("MyId")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `AndroidViewModel` as follow:

```
@HiltViewModel
class RecordSoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val appContext: Application,                
): AndroidViewModel(appContext) {
    ....
}
```

No need to pass application reference in when initializing viewModel in Fragment/Activity

```
private val viewModel : RecordSoundViewModel by viewModels()
```