# Why can the ViewModel created by Hilt automatically use Application in Android Studio?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I know `"A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context."`, so in order to use `Application`, I need to use `AndroidViewModel` just like Code A.

At present, I use Hilt as DI in Android Studio project, Code B works well, it seems I can use `Application` in  `ViewModel` created by Hilt automatically, why ?

BTW, it seems that `ViewModel` has bound `Application` based the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76152338/why-am-i-able-to-use-application-as-default-bindings-in-viewmodelcomponent-with).

**Code A**

```
class RecordSoundViewModel (
    private val appContext: Application,                
): AndroidViewModel(appContext) {
    ....
}
```

**Code B**

```
@HiltViewModel
class RecordSoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext val myContext: Context, //Lint: This field leaks a context object
    private val appContext: Application         //It's OK, why doesn't Android Studio display warning information        
): ViewModel()
{
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally in Hilt `Application` itself always a part of dependency graph so you can inject it everywhere. It can also be used as `Context`.

In first case it's just basic viewmodel that I assume you create with default viewmodel factory. It only supports constructors with Application and/or SavedStateHandle arguments (or none).

As for `@HiltViewModel` there's a bit of bytecode manipulation happening under the hood that replaces `ViewModel` factory with one that satisfies your `@Inject` constructor.
You're asking for it by using `by viewModels()` within an activity or fragment marked as `@AndroidEntryPoint`.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you first run your application you are using **@HiltAndroidApp** in Application class.

> All apps using Hilt must contain an Application class annotated with
> **@HiltAndroidApp**. @HiltAndroidApp kicks off the code generation of the
> Hilt components and also generates a base class for your application
> that uses those generated components. Because the code generation
> needs access to all of your modules, the target that compiles your
> Application class also needs to have all of your Dagger modules in its
> transitive dependencies.

When the source code is examined, it is clearly seen that **@ApplicationContext** is a singleton. It provides you access from wherever you want and facilitates its creation.

[image: Dagger Hilt Application Context Provides]